# Oracle: add ON DELETE CASCADE to foreign key used in partition by reference

Tags: oracle, partitioning, cascading-deletes

Is it possible to add ON DELETE CASCADE to a foreign key that is used as a partitioning key when used with PARTITION BY REFERENCE? I'm talking about an already exiting table.

My solution would be to drop the constraint and recreate it, but it doesn't work, as I cannot drop a constraint that is used by PARTITION BY REFERENCE.

I get
SQL Error: ORA-14650: operation not supported for reference-partitioned tables

Oracle 11g.

```
drop table y;
drop table x;
create table x (a number primary key) partition by hash (a);
create table y (a number not null,
   constraint y_x_fk foreign key(a) references x(a))
   partition by reference(y_x_fk);
alter table y drop constraint y_x_fk;
```

Comment: Something I'm not getting: you want to change the y_x_fk constraint to be on delete cascade? And you say you can't delete it? You sure?

Comment: Yes, I get ORA-14650 when trying to drop the constraint. The table is partitioned by reference and this FK is the partition key and you can't just drop such a constraint.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no option in `ALTER...MODIFY` to an inline option to make the extant constraint cascade; I think you will indeed need to drop and recreate, or equivalent.

I also agree, it looks like there is no clean way to drop and recreate a partition-reference constraint either; I believe you'll be facing a redefiniton to get there.

To make matters worse, it looks like the `DBMS_REFEFINITION` enhancements available in 12c won't get you there in a nice one-step redef, as `DBMS_REDEFINITION` [doesn't support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-54D18B18-6838-4115-9389-E1FB0D20A8CA.htm) reference partitioning.

I think you'll need to do an old-school redef.  (It could still be worth trying some `DBMS_REDEFINITION` with a hand-crafted replacement, but I would be prepared for at least a bit of downtime).

An approach like the below example could get you there (with downtime).  Depending on your availability needs, other approaches could minimize the downtime in this example.

Make a replacement table with the desired `CASCADING FK`:

```
create table y_temp (a number not null,
  constraint y_temp_x_fk foreign key(a) references x(a) ON DELETE CASCADE)
partition by reference(y_temp_x_fk);
```

Then go read-only:

```
ALTER TABLE X READ ONLY;
ALTER TABLE Y READ ONLY;
```

Then sync `Y` and `Y_TEMP`:

```
INSERT INTO Y_TEMP SELECT Y.A FROM Y;
COMMIT;
```

Then make the swap:

```
ALTER TABLE Y RENAME TO Y_OLD;
ALTER TABLE Y_TEMP RENAME TO Y;
DROP TABLE Y_OLD;
ALTER TABLE Y RENAME CONSTRAINT y_temp_x_fk TO y_x_fk;
```

And bring things back up for `WRITE`

```
ALTER TABLE X READ WRITE;
```

Then test it:

```
INSERT INTO X VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Y VALUES (1);

SELECT * FROM Y;

A  
1  

DELETE FROM X;

1 row deleted.
```

And the cascade:

```
SELECT * FROM Y;

no rows selected
```